# Is it a good idea and a logic to create adventure game with one scene?

Tags: unity

I mean instead messing with loading scenes and passing variables between the scenes to make one scene and using in the hierarchy empty game objects for each part in the game for example empty game object name main menu and all the childs of it will be main menu objects.

Or instead making a new scene to make one empty gameobject and all it's childs will be like scenes.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a way that you like to work, then go for it. You don't need our permission to give it a try. ;)

One note if you're working in a team though: coordinating work between multiple people on a single scene can be challenging. If you're using version control, scenes are usually set up for exclusive checkout, since merging changes can get tricky. That means one person working on a given scene can block other folks who need to make edits there.

(It can get hairy enough that I know one Unity game studio used to assign physical totem objects to each of their scene files: you weren't allowed to work on a particular scene unless you had the totem at your desk)

Splitting your game into multiple scenes can make this collaboration a little easier, but other workflows (like breaking the scene contents up into multiple independent prefabs) can help with this.

Comment: By the way, there are tools that allow your team to work on one scene. I don't want to advertise anyone here (it's against the rules), but there is a plug-in for unity. It's not free, though.

Answer (score 1):

It's a tricky question because all of it depends on the project. But there is one thing that should be considered.

The DATA.

Scene loading allows you to free your RAM memory from objects that are not active. In other words, if you have all of the objects on 1 scene, all of them will be loaded into RAM.

If you consider that and you see that you can't allow your game to take a lot of RAM memory, for example, 4GB. Then you would need to unload data/destroy objects and save their state anyway.

Usually while making the game the main factor between choosing to use multiple scenes or 1 scene depends on the type of the gameplay.

1. If you want it to be like a lot of AAA games that don't have these load screens and they load, for example, terrain in chunks - then you shouldn't consider using multiple scenes. But instead make your own loading methods.
2. This one is quite the opposite. If your gameplay can be interrupted and it's based on the chunks of story/levels... you can say for sure that you can use multiple scenes to make your life easier.

P.S. Clarification: many AAA games use 2 option as well. I didn't mean that AAA game should use option 1 always. Examples can be taken from many RTS games.